# Indentation issues with Emacs (Espresso in this case)

Tags: emacs

There is certainly something I miss in Emacs configuration regarding indentation.

Here is some JavaScript code I'd like to indent:

```
$(function(){
  $.superbox.settings = {
    closeTxt: "",
    loadTxt: "",
    [...]
```

If I do a `M-q` (i.e. `paredit-reindent-defun`) here is what I get:

```
$(function(){
  $.superbox.settings = {
                         closeTxt: "",
                         loadTxt: "",
```

How can I configure Emacs to follow more conventional indentation? In this particular case I'd like to see `closeTxt` one indentation (e.g. four spaces) further the `$.superbox` declaration one line above...

P.S. I use the emacs-starter-kit (https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit).

Comment: Why downvoting this question? At least give a comment to improve future questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`paredit` is poorly suited for anything other than Lisp editing. I would indent JavaScript code using it. You should try using the standard JavaScript indent defuns instead. Remove the following lines from `starter-kit-js.el`, restart Emacs and try again:

```
(add-hook 'espresso-mode-hook 'esk-paredit-nonlisp)
(eval-after-load 'espresso
  '(progn (define-key espresso-mode-map "{" 'paredit-open-curly)
          (define-key espresso-mode-map "}" 'paredit-close-curly-and-newline)
          ;; fixes problem with pretty function font-lock
          (define-key espresso-mode-map (kbd ",") 'self-insert-command)
          (font-lock-add-keywords
           'espresso-mode `(("\\(function *\\)("
                             (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
                                                       (match-end 1) "ƒ")
                                       nil)))))))
```

Comment: and what are the standard javascript indent defuns?

Comment: You'll have them automatically when you remove the paredit bindings. Most modes have I'm not familiar with the mode, but stuff like indent-region(C-M-\), etc are always available. Probably the mode implements stuff like indent-defun as well. You can see what you have available as functions/keybindings by pressing C-h m in a javascript buffer.